# Как в tkinter переключаться между вкладками/окнами приложения?

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть простая однооконная программка на питоне с Tkinter'ом, интересно, как переключаться между видами в ней. Виды отрисованы, когда пишу в дефнутой функции вид.mainloop() , при запуске программы открываются все виды сразу.

Comment: Скорее всего у вас все окна создаются ("отрисовываются") одновременно. Вынесите создание каждого окна в отдельную функцию, которую потом вызывайте когда нужно, а не при создании основного окна.

Comment: Для переключения между вклалками/окнами есть 3 способа. 1) - использовать `ttk.Notebook` тогда все окна вашей программы будут в одном окне, но на разных вкладках `Notebook`. 2) - открытие окон типа `tk.Toplevel()` при нажатии кнопки / при каком-то событии. 3) - создание несколько `tk.Frame`, которые будут переключаться между друг другом тоже при нажатии на кнопку / при каком-то событии. То есть один из `Frame` удаляется, а другой занимает его место.

Comment: @DGDays понял, а как удалить один из Frame ?

Comment: Смотря как вы его размещаете в окне. Если используете `pack()`, то для него `pack_forget()`. И так для остальных, только меняете `pack` на ваш метод размещения виджета.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создайте объект `n_book=ttk.Notebook()`
затем `frame1 = Frame()`

```
frame2 = Frame()
n_book.add(frame1,text="hi")
n_book.add(frame2,text="bye")
b1 = Button(frame1, text='hello')
b21 = Button(frame2, text='bye bye')
n_book.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()
```

Comment: Как это отвечает на вопрос "Как в tkinter переключаться между вкладками/окнами приложения?" ?

Comment: этот виджет помогает переключаться между вкладками , т.к. он создает вкладки